# Alternative of deprecated hibernate getSession().connection()

Tags: hibernate

When using HibernateDaoSupport class,I found that getSession().connection(); is deprecated.

What is another method,please,instead of this

Comment: this question is pretty thoroughly discussed here. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8770459/connection-getmetadata-does-not-seem-to-return-table-info

Answer (score 2):

Now we have to use  [session.doWork()](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#doWork%28org.hibernate.jdbc.Work%29) API:

```
session.doWork(
        new Work() {
            public void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException 
            { 
                doSomething(connection); 
            }
        }
    );
```

Refer also :[session.connection() deprecated on Hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526556/session-connection-deprecated-on-hibernate)

Comment: Last line of your post was enough to add as a comment to question, rather than posting a new answer. Nothing new other than API link.

Comment: @NayanWadekar Thanks for the concern. If you see that link there are 4 to 5 ways of getting connection object. But the one I written above looks better among those(As per my understanding after read all the possibilities there).

Comment: I think, a small green tick & the number of votes are enough to minimize the possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the following workaround for getting Session's connection without any deprecation. I'm pretty sure Hibernate's people didn't meant to allow this.

```
private static class WorkAround implements org.hibernate.jdbc.Work {
    private Connection conn = null;

    @Override
    public void execute(Connection conn) throws SQLException {
        this.conn = conn;
    }

    public Connection getConnection() {
        return conn;
    }

}

public static Connection getConnection(Session session) {
    WorkAround wrk = new WorkAround();
    session.doWork(wrk);
    return wrk.getConnection();
}
```

I wanted to post this answer here: [session.connection() deprecated on Hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526556/session-connection-deprecated-on-hibernate), but I see I'm not allowed to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl;

```
import org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl;
public static class WorkAround {
    public Connection getConnection(Session session){
            SessionImpl sessionImpl = (SessionImpl) session;
            return session.connection()
    }
}
```